# how to read a variable outside the try-catch block

Tags: java, android

I need to read the second value of `JsonArray` but I can't read it.

```
  public void onViewBind(View view, Cursor cursor, ODataRow row) {
    OControls.setText(view, R.id.name, row.getString("name"));
    OControls.setText(view, R.id.email, row.getString("message"));
    JSONArray partner_id = null;
    try {
        partner_id = new JSONArray(row.getString("student_id"));
        String name = partner_id.getString(1);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    OControls.setText(view, R.id.company_name,name);
  }
```

how can I access the variable `name` from outside of the try block?

Comment: Declare your variable before the `try` block .

Comment: Attention: If you get an exception the value is not set

Comment: read about scopes in java: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

Declare your **`String name`** variable outside `try-catch` block like below code

**Sample code**

```
 public void onViewBind(View view, Cursor cursor, ODataRow row) {
    OControls.setText(view, R.id.name, row.getString("name"));
    OControls.setText(view, R.id.email, row.getString("message"));
    JSONArray partner_id = null;
    String name ="";
    try {
        partner_id = new JSONArray(row.getString("student_id"));
        name = partner_id.getString(1);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    OControls.setText(view, R.id.company_name,name);
  }
```

OR THIS

```
 public void onViewBind(View view, Cursor cursor, ODataRow row) {
        OControls.setText(view, R.id.name, row.getString("name"));
        OControls.setText(view, R.id.email, row.getString("message"));
        JSONArray partner_id = null;
        String name ="";
        try {
            partner_id = new JSONArray(row.getString("student_id"));
            String name = partner_id.getString(1);
            OControls.setText(view, R.id.company_name,name);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare name outside try catch block

```
        public void onViewBind(View view, Cursor cursor, ODataRow row) {
        OControls.setText(view, R.id.name, row.getString("name"));
        OControls.setText(view, R.id.email, row.getString("message"));
                JSONArray partner_id = null;
                String name=""; 
          try {


                partner_id = new JSONArray(
                        row.getString("student_id"));
               name = partner_id.getString(1);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
             }


        OControls.setText(view, R.id.company_name,name);
```

hopefully that helps

Comment: In your code you can only access name variable in try block because you declare and initialize it in try block

Answer (score 0):

The following error will be raised:

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value 6 of type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

*6 will be replaced with another integer in your example*

Instead of using `JSonArray` with `try-catch` use `student_id` to get the student record then use it to get any attibute you need:

```
// Check first if "student_id" is available
if(!row.getString("student_id").equals("false")) {
    Student student_obj = new Student(getContext(), null);
    ODataRow student = student_obj.browse(row.getInt("student_id"));

    // Here you can get any student attribute from student record.
}
```

When you can use programing to avoid `try-catch` do it, because it is better.